# AngularJS - Pass $index or the item itself via ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, scope

Say I have

```
<div ng-repeat="item in scope.allItems">
   <div ng-click="doSomething(...)"></div>
</div>
```

If I want to do something with `item` upon click, which one is a better option?

**Option 1**

Use `ng-click="doSomething($index)` and have:

```
$scope.doSomething = function($index) {
    var myItem = $scope.allItems[$index];
}
```

**Option 2**

Use `ng-click="doSomething(item)` and have:

```
$scope.doSomething = function(myItem) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just doing something to the item, pass that in.  This way the function doesn't need to know which array the item belongs to:

```
$scope.addColor = function(car) {
  car.color = 'red';
};
```

If, on the other hand, you need to modify the array I prefer to pass in $index and save having to loop through the array looking for a match:

```
$scope.deleteCar = function(index, cars) {
  cars.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: If I am just going to grab some information from `item`, but not change or modify it in anyway, then what?

Comment: same thing - if the function doesn't need to access the whole array, just pass in the item.  maybe you can get away with passing in just the item.property that you need, instead of the whole item?

Answer (score 1):

If you want use filter for scope.allItems, use Option 2 - because using filters change element $index. 
If you don't use filter,you can use Option 1.
IMHO Option 2 more easy and useful than Option 1, so i already use Option 2.